# Revert to pre-git v1.7.8 git submodule behavior with submodule filesystem locations

Tags: git, git-submodules

Recently in git 1.7.8, a change was introduced to "handle" submodules differently than before - https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/12/2/316

> When populating a new submodule directory with "git submodule init",
>   the $GIT_DIR metainformation directory for submodules is created inside
>   $GIT_DIR/modules// directory of the superproject and referenced
>   via the gitfile mechanism. This is to make it possible to switch
>   between commits in the superproject that has and does not have the
>   submodule in the tree without re-cloning.

So now, instead of cloning the submodule into the specified directory, instead a .git *file* is created and within it is this:

```
$ cat .git
gitdir: ../../../../.git/modules/app/src/emberlabs/openflame
```

My problem: I'm on git 1.7.9, and I need the files of the cloned submodule to be in my local clone exactly where I expect them, instead of where git dictates they should be - as was the behavior before git 1.7.8, where I could ls the submodule's clone directory and find all files of the cloned commit present.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to...well, ***re***-achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution to this.

Editing the file the `{$project_root}/.git/modules/{$submodule_path}/.git/config` and removing the `worktree` line under `[core]`, and copying over the entire .git directory from `{$project_root}/.git/modules/{$submodule_path}/` into the submodule's actual location (after deleting the `.git` *file* where the submodule was) and then running `git checkout -f {$branch}` seems to have pulled all files back up.  Not entirely sure that it is a full solution however.

Comment: Did you ever find an easier solution?  I'm experiencing the same issue and I'm using the latest version of GIT.  I should be able to easily clone like old-times w/out having to mess with all this nonsense.  I want my submodules to copy over as legit repos that can be amended and pushed.

Comment: I had to do this to get Gitbox to track my submodule correctly. Worked perfectly.