# git submodules - error: could not lock config file .git/modules/path/to/vimlib/config: No such file or directory

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

This is a weird one. I created a repo years ago:
https://github.com/todd-dsm/vimSimple

I used submodules at the time; thought it was a good idea; it's been a PITA since then. I now need to update some of those submodules and I get this error on every single one

```
% git submodule deinit -f vim/bundle/tlib_vim 
Cleared directory 'vim/bundle/tlib_vim'
error: could not lock config file .git/modules/vim/bundle/tlib_vim/config: No such file or directory
warning: Could not unset core.worktree setting in submodule 'vim/bundle/tlib_vim'
```

It doesn't matter which submodule I choose, it's the same error as there is no 'modules' directory:

```
% ls -al .git/modules
ls: cannot access '.git/modules': No such file or directory
```

Effectively, I've created an 'updates' branch, deleted some submodules:

```
othree/html5.vim.git
rodjek/vim-puppet.git
rodjek/puppet-lint.git
pearofducks/ansible-vim
python-mode/python-mode
elzr/vim-json
hashivim/vim-hashicorp-tools
```

Now, I need to `update` the remaining submodules:

```
% git config --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp path                      
submodule.vim/bundle/syntastic.path
submodule.vim/bundle/tlib_vim.path
submodule.vim/bundle/vim-addon-mw-utils.path
submodule.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive.path
submodule.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate.path
submodule.vim/bundle/vim-snippets.path
submodule.vim/bundle/vim-lint.path
submodule.vim/bundle/Dockerfile.path
submodule.vim/bundle/L9.path
submodule.vim/bundle/vim-autocomplpop.path
```

It seems like it used to work one way and now, years later, it works another.
Is there any way out of this? How would one solve this problem?

Comment: Submodules, aka sob-modules  . I have not tried this with an old submodule setup, but in theory `git submodule absorbgitdirs` should patch a bunch of stuff up so that modern Git submodule commands work a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like it used to work one way and now, years later, it works another.

Yes, [since Git 1.7.8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9459532/6309), the submodule is in [`$GIT_DIR/modules/<name>/`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8b0e15fa95e11965f18c8d2585dc8ffd9bfc9356/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt#L47-L52) (that is `.git/modules/<name>` usually), and no longer in the submodule folder itself (`<name>/.git`).

Check if your own submodules were created pre 1.7.8 (meaning before Q3 2011, eleven years ago).

If so, the `git submodule deinit` would not be efficient, and simply removing your submodule root folder should be enough (as well as updating manually the `.gitmodules` file of your main repository).

From there, you can add those submodules back, using a recent Git.

Comment: Excellent; thank you confirming. Now I can go back to feeling sane again.